# Integrating Google Maps Traffic and Transit in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps

Is there some manner to download and shown Google Traffic and Transit layers in QGIS? Something made with a Plugin or inserting a shapefile.

Answer (score 5):

Using **XYZ tiles** [No plugin required]

**Traffic** (where available)

```
https://mt0.google.com/vt?lyrs=h@159000000,traffic|seconds_into_week:-1&style=3&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

**Transit** (where available)

```
 https://mt0.google.com/vt?lyrs=h@159000000,transit|seconds_into_week:-1&style=3&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

[image]